# How to read a binary file that was written with QDataStream with std::ifstream

Tags: c++, qt, fstream

I want to read a binary file that was written with a `QDataStream` and encoding in LittleEndian with a `std::fstream` (on the same platform, so issues of one data type having a different format are not of concern).

How do I best do this? As far as I'm aware, `std::fstream` has no built in functionality to read/write LittleEndian data.

I dug into the problem and found out the following (pseudocode):

```
ofstream out;      //initialized to file1, ready to read/write
ifstream in;       //initialized to file2; ready to read/write
QDataStream q_out; //initialized to file2; ready to read/write

int a=5, b;
//write to file1
out << a; //stored as 0x 35 00 00 00. Curiously, 0x35 is the character '5' in ASCII-code
//write to file2
q_out << a; //stored as 0x 05 00 00 00

//read from file2 the value that was written by q_out
in >> b; //will NOT give the correct result

//read as raw data
char *c = new char[4];
in.read(c, 4);

unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char *)&b;
dst[3] = c[3];
dst[2] = c[2];
dst[1] = c[1];
dst[0] = c[0];
//b==5 now
```

To sum it up: `QDataStream` writes binary data in a different format than `std::fstream`. Is there an easy way to read binary data written by `QDataStream` using `std::fstream`?

Comment: No, you have to do the byte and word swapping yourself.

Comment: Aaaand, what machine are you on? Big or little endian?

Comment: little endian, I'd say?

Comment: And you're opening your `fstream`'s in `ios::binary` mode? We're missing that part of your setup code.

Comment: Yes I am. I omitted that part to make my point clearer.

Comment: I had the same problem than you and made this framelet: https://github.com/AndrePuel/BinaryStream

Comment: @AndréPuel: But your framelet doesn't deal with the differences in encoding between ios::fstream and QDataStream, right?

Comment: @mort It lets you specify if you wanna deal with Little or Big endian. https://github.com/Andrepuel/BinaryStream/blob/master/tests/primitives.cpp#L21
BinaryStream has the same objective than QDataStream: "A data stream is a binary stream of encoded information which is 100% independent of the host computer's operating system, CPU or byte order."
You just have to find out if QDataStream save stuff as little or big endian. Probably little endian.

Comment: @AndréPuel: QDataStream uses little endian. The issue is that it encodes an int differently than a std::fstream, as I tried to explain in my question. I think the easiest way for me to solve this is the way ybungalobill suggested

Comment: @mort fstream uses ascii to represent numbers, while QDataStream uses binary data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on a Little Endian machine, which is very likely, then reading a file containing the following int:

```
05 00 00 00
```

is as straight forward as:

```
int32_t x;
in.read((char*)&x, sizeof(int32_t));
assert(x == 5);
```

Few more notes:

- Operators `>>` and `<<` do formatted i/o, that is they convert the values to/from the text representation, which is not related to your case.
- You should open the files in binary mode (`ios_base::binary` flag). POSIX does not distinguish between binary and text, but some other OSes does.

Comment: "they convert the values to/from the text representation" That was a good hint. But why do the >> and << operators for a QDataStream not convert the values to/from text representation?

Comment: @mort: why would they? Qt is a completely different library following completely different guidelines.

Comment: @mort: Because that's what QTextStream is for.

Comment: This supposes that the endian-ness will never change.  From experience, it does; I've even had it change from one version of the compiler to the next.  This is an example of how to create a long term problem.